# How to set column values in a record set in access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

Given below is the working code. Previously I was using the .Name property that didn't work. 
Previous code:

```
      For Each s In rs.Fields
            word = Replace(strArray(count), """", "")
            count = count + 1
        'the below line shows error
            s.Name = word
        Next
```

New Complete working code. It opens a dialog for user to select the .csv file and then imports all the data into the table from that csv file.

```
    strMsg = "Select the file from which you want to import data"
mypath = GetPath(strMsg, True)
mypath = mypath

Dim strFilename As String: strFilename = mypath
Dim strTextLine As String
Dim strArray() As String
Dim count As Integer

Dim regex As New RegExp
regex.IgnoreCase = True
regex.Global = True
'This pattern matches only commas outside quotes
'Pattern = ",(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*(?![^"]*"))"
regex.Pattern = ",(?=([^""]*""[^""]*"")*(?![^""]*""))"

Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
Open strFilename For Input As #iFile
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
count = 0

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strTextLine
    count = 0

'regex.replaces will replace the commas outside quotes with <???> and then the
'Split function will split the result based on our replacement
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    strTextLine = regex.Replace(strTextLine, "<???>")
    strArray = Split(regex.Replace(strTextLine, "<???>"), "<???>")
    Set rs = db("AIRLINES").OpenRecordset
    Dim word As Variant
    With rs
        .AddNew
        For Each s In rs.Fields
            word = Replace(strArray(count), """", "")
            count = count + 1
        'the below line shows error
            s.Value = word
        Next
        .Update
        .Close
    End With
lpp:
    Loop

db.Close
Close #iFile
MsgBox ("Imported Successfully")
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
   Resume lpp
```

Comment: Maybe `s.Value = word` ?

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: @A.S.H I didn't increment the count variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the Name property. Use Value.

How are you populating the array? If it has base index of 0, then increment Count after setting the field value.

Comment: It does for me. What happens - error message, wrong results, nothing? Edit question to post the entire procedure.

Comment: It worked thanks I'll paste the complete code working code.

Comment: Sorry I was in a rush that day. I had to meet the deadline so I went ahead with the long method where I had to specify the column names of all 26 columns and then assign values to them.